# Blank screen on custom error 404 page

Tags: asp-classic, http-status-code-404, iis-8, custom-errors

In IIS 8.5, I have a default web site with a custom page that handles 404 errors.

This custom page is default.asp, which is also the site's default document.

When a 404 error occurs and the default.asp happens to have any other error (for instance, a SQL query timeout), IIS shows only a blank page and not the actual error.

If default.asp is accessed explicitly (no 404 error), the error is correctly shown.

Steps to reproduce this problem:

1. Configure a web site with a 404 error document pointing to default.asp
2. Create a default.asp with a divide by zero error: <%=1/0%>
3. Access /notexists.htm in your site. A blank screen is shown.
4. Access /default.asp. A divide by zero error is shown, which was also expected in step 3.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Errors will return a status of 500-100, internal server error. So you might want to seperate out the 404 file not found, and 500-100 error pages.

Comment: I have a custom 500-100 error page (/error.asp) which sends me an e-mail and shows a generic error page. The message is sent but the page shown is blank, if the error happened in the 404 custom error page.